# Installation of Libsodium on a Azure Web App

Tags: php, azure, pear, pecl, libsodium

I've been trying to install Libsodium on my PHP Web App in Azure, but there's a few permission issues that I've encounted.
I've been following this link here to try and install it: https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/00-intro.md#installing-libsodium but it requires me to place the libsodium.dll file into the same directory as the php.exe file - where I obviously don't have the correct permissions to write into, which is probably the cause of this error in the command line:

ERROR: The DSP libsodium.dsp does not exist.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you tried to install the extension with `pecl install libsodium`, which is hard to get working on Windows.

This is the reason that you're advised to download the `.dll` and use that.
Even if you would get `pecl install libsodium` to work, it would also only have created a `.dll` file that you need to activate in PHP.

So you're lost until you get write access to that php.exe directory.

Answer (score 0):

Does it change anything if that DLL is on the `%PATH%`?

If that works, then you can build an XDT transform to add an arbitraty folder to the system `%PATH%`. Here's how: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Xdt-transform-samples#adding-environment-variables

Comment: At this point i'd switch to App Service on Linux and bring my own container with all the dependencies thrown in the Dockerfile -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-using-custom-docker-image